# audio tab will not play in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio

I have the following 3 web pages.  The objective was to go to a newPage and have audio playing in the background.  It works fine in Firefox and IE Edge but the audio doesn't play in chrome.  Any way to fix this?

submit.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>   
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

<script>
  function playAudio(){
      window.open('http://localhost/Audio/src/NewPage.html');      
      return ;
  }   
</script>

<title>Submit</title>
```

newPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>newPage</title>
</head>
<body>
   here we are
</body>
</html>
```

audio.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>audio page</title>
</head> 
<body>

   <audio autoplay loop controls>
           <source src="audio/Drunken-Sailer-Irish-Rovers.mp3" type=audio/mp3>           
   </audio> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried going to chrome://flags/ and disable the option #disable-gesture-requirement-for-media-playback ? Does it change anything?

Comment: Thanks, that does work.  Is there a way to play continuous music while moving from page to page on a web site?  Without having to have the user select special flags or allow pop ups?

Comment: As far as I know, playback of background music is now disabled by default by chrome in order to spare computing/energy resources, the user is expected to visit the tab before the media is fully loaded. The following issue refers to it https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=572387 . So the problem resides in the browser specifically opposing what you are trying to do, not in your code. I don't know whether there are ways to go around this without requiring the user to change that option flag.